# Is it possible to catch or hatch Pokémon far above your trainer level?

Tags: pokemon-go

It was my understanding that you could only ever have a Pokémon who is a level and a half above your current trainer level. Yet the other day I saw a Pokémon in a gym, that seemed to exceed the trainers level by more than that.

According to the tools provided by [The SilphRoad](https://thesilphroad.com/research), a Gyarados at level 21.5 (1.5 above the level 20 trainer) should have a maximum CP of 1651.  However, the Gyarados in the gym had a CP of 2200. Which again, according to the SilphRoad tools, should only be able to be owned by a level 28 trainer.

Is it possible to catch or hatch a Pokémon that exceeds your level by more than 1.5? Or are the SilphRoad tools inaccurate?

Comment: I wonder if the 1.5 level restriction will still be enforced, if/when trading is added to the game.

Comment: I would encourage you to take a screenshot the next time you think you see this (and share it).

Comment: @Eikre I agree, I wish I would have captured a screenshot. It's possible that I read the trainer's level incorrectly, and the '0' was actually an '8'.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, that shouldn't be possible. I have found no evidence to support that the 1.5 level bump can be surpassed regardless of how you obtained the Pokemon.

That said, maybe the person in question had a hacked mon?